# C++ visual studio function syntax highlighting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there any way in visual studio 2017 community to have syntax highlighting for C++ functions? Ive looked around and weirdly cant find much info on this. It could be an issue only im having, if so, does anyone know why this might be happening.

Ill elaborate in the form of photos:
[This is in Visual Studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAhI4.png)

[This is in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFvL6.png)

Comment: Check out Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors. If you scroll down there should be some stuff for c++ syntax highlighting, though I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: That was exactly what i was wanting, Thank-you. I however have another question: how do i mark this as solved?

Comment: Tim, if @Unlocked had posted their answer as an actual answer, you could mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), which would mark the question as solved. They posted a comment instead, but you could write your own answer (it's perfectly fine to answer your own questions) with the exact setting which helped you, properly cite the comment which guided you there, and accept that.

Comment: I'll post it as a formal answer so you can mark it. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors. If you scroll down there should be some items for c++ syntax highlighting.